# CQL : InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]

Tags: cassandra

```
create table cd_ml_api.sf_leads (
    id timeuuid,
    email text ,
    cdh_org text,
    source_of_funds text ,
    currency_purpose text ,
    created_date timestamp,
    last_modified_date timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (email, last_modified_date)
)  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id DESC);
```

Showing error in cassandra terminal :

> InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] 
>   
>                     message="Missing CLUSTERING ORDER for column last_modified_date"

Answer (score 0):

```
create table cd_ml_api.sf_leads (
    id timeuuid,
    email text ,
    cdh_org text,
    source_of_funds text ,
    currency_purpose text ,
    created_date timestamp,
    last_modified_date timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (email, last_modified_date)
)  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (last_modified_date DESC);
```

Cassandra can sort by clustering key only.
In order to sort by id it has to be part of clustering key.